# how to get the week from date formulae field in salesforce?

Tags: formula-field

i want to display the week in field labale by using the formulae field, in manually sdcsacascaDaDXCAScASC DADdasdq

Comment: What do you mean by week?  The day of the week (e.g., Sunday, Monday, etc.) or the week of the year (e.g., 26, 27, 28, 51 week of the year)?

Answer (score 1):

I think your requirement can be found [here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&language=en_US#week-of-year) in the provided common date formulas.